# Python list changing order

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've the following code:

```
for i in xrange(len(arr_id)):
    list.append({'id': arr_id[i], 'porcentaje' : 0, 'estado' : 'En funcionamiento'})
```

If I print `list` it seems I get a alphabetically ordered list:
`[{'estado': 'En funcionamiento', 'id': 0, 'porcentaje': 0}]`

Which is not in the same order I define it:
`[{'id': 0,  'porcentaje': 0, 'estado': 'En funcionamiento',}]`

What can I do to maintain the desired order?

Comment: Python dictionaries have no set order. Why do you need the dictionary key order to be maintained?

Comment: You're sorting a list where there is only one item, it's a dictionnary. Python dictionnary does not have an 'order' as Martinjn pointed out.

Comment: Because this createst a `json` and I need an exact order to read them in Java.

Comment: @Borja: JSON objects have no order either. Even if you sorted the keys, Java would be free to decode them in a different order.

Comment: @Borja: use a list of key-value tuples instead if order is important.

Comment: You *can* maintain the order by using a data structure that keeps track of order on top of a regular dict, but usually, you don't need it. Consider whether this is just surprising or actually a problem, and remember that your dict doesn't need to keep its keys in any particular order for you to iterate through its keys in an order you choose.

Answer (score 3):

First, the list will maintain the order, but the dictionaries inside the list won't, because dictionary are by definition unordered. There is a datatype called [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) that does retain order, but I doubt you really need that.

A few other comments:

Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Don't iterate as if Python were C. You can iterate directly:

```
for item in arr_id:
    mylist.append({'id': item, 'porcentaje' : 0, 'estado' : 'En funcionamiento'})
```

or even use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
mylist = [{'id': item, 'porcentaje' : 0, 'estado' : 'En funcionamiento'}
          for item in arr_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not dealing with a list right now. You're dealing with a dictionnary nested into a list (which is pointless since there is only one item in your list)

You can't "sort" a dictionnary, because it's too easy to get it's value from a key. In your case :

```
>>> x = {'estado': 'En funcionamiento', 'id': 0, 'porcentaje': 0}
>>> x['estado']
b"En funcionamiento"
```

So there is no need to sort a dictionnary.

Though you can show a sorted representation of your dict. It would be only for printing purpose though.

```
import operator
x = {'estado': 'En funcionamiento', 'id': 0, 'porcentaje': 0}
sorted_x = sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Or as other answers pointed out, you could use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to retain the order of your dict.